# "can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property"

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6

Getting this error on Safari 10

Happens when a const is given a name that's exactly the same as an `id` of any element on the page.

```
const abc = document.querySelector("#abc"); //err
const abz = document.querySelector("#abc"); //no err
var abc = document.querySelector("#abc"); //no err
```

Is there a reason for this?
I know you can access the elements via window.abc, is that part of the why?

Test:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<div id="alpha"></div>
<script>
    const alpha = document.querySelector('#alpha');
    console.log(alpha);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/zxetwe5q/1/) (STP 10.1)

Comment: Errr well that's jsfiddle. Try it raw? I'll post a test.

Comment: Just tried on it STP, same error.

Comment: I can replicate with HTML, thanks. The error doesn't occur if you run `const alpha...` in a `setTimeout` callback. It looks like a temporal binding bug in Safari. I guess that's why a fiddle doesn't hit it.

Comment: @joews But `const` in `setTimeout` would be scoped to the callback function called after timeout, not the global scope, so it doesn't really relate to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, but it still "shadows a global property" so I was interested to see what happened in a different scope.

Comment: @joews it's a "problem" with the standards, actually. HTML elements with IDs will get an entry under the `window` object so you can have `<div id="myDiv"/>` and you can then fetch it by doing `myDiv` (implicitly fetching it from `window`. If you declare a `const myDiv` in the global scope, it'd consider that "trying to redefine" `myDiv`.

Comment: @vlaz But unlike`var`, `const` and `let` do not create global properties

Comment: @Oriol yes, but I'm guessing that's not _exactly_ how Safari sees it. Actually re-reading the error message, it complains about shadowing the global property, so it seems to understand that `const myDiv` will be a _different_ thing yet it also realises that it clashes with `window.myDiv`. I'm guessing it's a Safari bug. I'd say that _sensibly_ it should blitz over the property, seeing how bad in general that standard is. It's adopted _from_ IE to begin with and even Edge doesn't conform to it now. Browsers are also supposed to do entries for elements with an unique `name` but only IE does it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is apparently a problem Safari has with declaring a let/const variable that shares the same name as a selected id attribute. I had some variables declared with const as you did and got the same error. Changed to let and still got it. Changed to var and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved my today's problem with Safari. I want that state that I hate Safari more than IE !

Comment: Wow... this is awful... one year later and still not fixed... is safari becoming the new IE ???

Comment: I have no words. Just... wow. A quick search and replace of const to var fixed it.

Comment: Solvem my problem with WKWebViews in iOS too.

Comment: Thank you. Here we are in 2023 and this problem still exists in Safari. I changed const to var and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This must be linked to [this webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159270)

In the meantime you may either replace `const` by `var`, or change the name of your variable (eg: *_alpha*).

Answer (score 0):

Nathan's answer is correct. Instead of using var I just changed my const to have a different case than the id. So...

```
const Abc = document.querySelector("#abc");
```

Still hacky, just another option.