# Correct or standard way to write non-'terminating' code?

Tags: javascript

Apologies, but I'm not sure what the term for what I'm asking is.

What I'm referring to is when a bit of code fails and prevents any further code from executing.
When chucks of code are not dependent on each other, there's no reason the failure of one chunk should stop the rest right?

Example:

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('#alphaDiv');
div1.style.color = 'red';

const div2 = document.querySelector('#bravoDiv');
div2.style.display = 'flex';
```

if for some reason there's an error with the `div1` code, the execution would stop there and `div2`'s code would never run.
To address this, I've always used a `setTimeout` or `try catch` to segment non-interdependent code/function calls.

Is that generally how it's done? Or is there a standard best practice for this sort of contingency?
Also, is there a generic term for what I'm referring to?

**Edit**
I'm specifically asking for client side, when things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091136) occur.
It just seems like a losing battle to discover and handle every tiny quirk of every browser.

Comment: The *correct* way to do this is to handle your errors, or prevent them in the first place. If you know a variable may contain `undefined`, *test for that condition*, and handle it.

Comment: `Also, is there a generic term for what I'm referring to?` Error handling? Also, with your example, it's not really clear to the JS engine if two pieces of code are "unrelated". Let's assume for a moment that you have a problem with `div1` but continue and `div2` works fine - what if 10 or 500 lines down you do `div1.text = div2.text` - what then? By not failing, your code will _change what it's doing_ and you'd never know unless you notice the output is different but even then you won't know _why_.

Comment: I usually check if the variable is undefined or null before assigning anything in such cases.

Comment: I should've clarified I'm specifically asking about client-side. There's seemingly a billion different ways things can go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, coding isn't just a matter of programming for the "happy path", when everything goes as expected. Robust code MUST anticipate and handle bad or unexpected input (ie data). if statements and try / catch are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to balance the probability that something fails.

For example, you don't need `try...catch` if your `document.querySelector` don't throw.

However, `document.querySelector` will throw if the browser does not recognize `#alphaDiv` as a valid selector. But the probability of encountering a browser which doesn't support ID selectors is probably negligible. As an alternative you can consider `document.getElementById`. It will be faster, and should never throw.

Excluding `querySelector` errors, you can check that every value on which you attempt to retrieve a property or which you attempt to call really exists. Something like

```
if (document.querySelector) {
  // Let's assume the browser can parse CSS ID selectors
  const div1 = document.querySelector('#alphaDiv');
  if (div1 && div1.style) {
    div1.style.color = 'red';
  }
  const div2 = document.querySelector('#bravoDiv');
  if (div2 && div2.style) {
    div2.style.display = 'flex';
  }
}
```

There are also some assumptions in there, e.g. that  if `document.querySelector` is truthy, then it has the proper value.

But even when coding defensively like this, there can still be problems. If I recall correctly, old versions of IE threw an error when assigning unsupported CSS values in `style`.

So you must decide, if you want your code to be completely safe, probably it's better to use `try...catch`. But it's ugly and  may make the code slower on some engines. And usually it's not worth it.

You also mention `setTimeout`. That can work, but has remember it's asynchronous. Depending on what you want to do, this can be a problem.

Comment: `document.querySelector` will not throw an exception, because #alphaDiv is a valid selector. It may not reference an element in the DOM, in which case it will return null, but it will not throw an exception. Only if the selector is invalid will it throw an exception.

Comment: @mangotang `div:has(>p)` is also a valid selector according to CSS Selectors 4 and will throw on most browsers. Of course `:has` is defined in a draft and `#alphaDiv` became standard much before `querySelector`, so an error is a remote possibility in this case. I'm just saying `querySelector` can throw for some selectors.

Comment: Thanks! And yea, I do also use `if` checks but those can often get quite long depending on how many variables, so I just opt for one of the other to be lazy :P

Comment: I've been using all 3 of them for years now, just never really thought about it. Buta, can you think of any other non-niche ways of doing this? Or are those 3 what's generally used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Placing your code in a try / catch is a reasonable thing to do to insure that errors (aka exceptions) don't cause your program to fail and terminate early. For instance:

```
try {
     const div1 = document.querySelector('#alphaDiv');
     div1.style.color = 'red';
} catch (e) {
     console.error('div1 is null');
}

try {
     const div2 = document.querySelector('#bravoDiv');
     div2.style.display = 'flex';
} catch (e) {
     console.error('div2 is null');
}
```

You could also check the state of your application to verify that your next statement won't cause a problem. For instance, in your example code you could modify it to do something like:

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('#alphaDiv');
if (div1) {
    div1.style.color = 'red';
}

const div2 = document.querySelector('#bravoDiv');
if (div2) {
    div2.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

NOTE: looks like document.querySelector can throw an exception if the selector is garbage, for instance:

```
document.querySelector("@#$%")
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` may throw.

Comment: @Oriol It's important to pick your battles.

Comment: @Oriol No, it may not. The selectors as written are syntactically valid and cannot become syntactically invalid, as they are string literals. Are you suggesting you should wrap every use of `querySelector` in a `try/catch` statement incase the selector *you typed yourself* somehow becomes syntactically invalid on some user's computer?

Comment: @meagar I'm not suggesting to do that, I'm just warning about the remote possibility that an error might happen, which seems to make OP worry. I posted an answer to clarify.

Comment: @Oriol The "remote possibility" here seems to involve a runtime that cannot be trusted. If talking to the DOM via `querySelector` cannot be trusted to work, the correct thing for your code to do is *probably* to die. I don't think unexpected undefined behavior from `querySelector` is something you should worry about handling and recovering from.