# Snapping Drag and Drop Items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use drag and drop to move pictures from one `<div>` to another.

Currently, I can move the pictures anywhere in the destination `<div>`, but what I really want is that the pictures snap together when dropped. Ideally, they would be able to snap together on any side (not just, for example, on the bottom or on the right).

I've tried a few different things (including using `<canvas>`) and it didn't work.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var clone;
var offsetx = null;
var offsety = null;
var isClone = false;

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  offsetx = ev.target.offsetLeft - event.clientX;
  offsety = ev.target.offsetTop - event.clientY;
  
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dropTrash(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var remove = document.getElementById(data);

  remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}

function dropClone(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var num = Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1;
  
  isClone = true;   
    
  clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "newId" + num.toString();
  clone.style.position = "absolute";
  clone.style.left = (event.clientX+offsetx)+"px";
  clone.style.top = (event.clientY+offsety)+"px"; 

  ev.target.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
}

div { 
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50%; 
  float: left; 
}

#div1 { 
  background: #DDD; 
}

#div2 {
  background: #AAA; 
}

#div3 {
  background: #777; 
}

#div4 { 
  background: #444; 
}

#imgDiv {
  width: 611px;
  height: 324px;
  border: 5px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
</div>

<div id="div2">
</div>

<div id="div3" ondrop="dropTrash(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img  id="drag1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Bartagame_fcm.jpg/1200px-Bartagame_fcm.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="105" height="105">
  <img  id="drag2" src="http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/lizard_Ngo_Van_Tri_big_281.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="105" height="105"> 
</div>

<div id="div4">
  <div align="center" id="imgDiv" ondrop="dropClone(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start dragging an image, you need to store the position of the cursor, relative to that particular image.

There are multiple position properties in the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) that will help you calculate that, but if browser support is not an issue, I would go for [MouseEvent.offsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [MouseEvent.offsetY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY). From the docs:

> The `offsetX`/`offsetY` read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the `X`/`Y` coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

So, on [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart), you will do just:

```
x = e.offsetX;
y = e.offsetY;
```

Then, when you drop the image in your, let's call it *canvas* (note the italics as it is not a `<canvas>` element, but any other element that you use as your drop zone, a `<div>` in this particular example), you need to know the position of the cursor relative to that canvas, so you may think you could use `offsetX` and `offsetY` again, and your are partially right. That would give you the expected value if you drop the image on the *canvas* itself, but there may be other images in it already, and you may drop the current one on top of another one, getting the `offsetX` and `offsetY` relative to that one instead.

What you can do is use [`MouseEvent.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [`MouseEvent.pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY) and, from that value, subtract the position of the (upper-left corner) of that *canvas* element, which you can get from [HTMLElement.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) and [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop):

```
e.pageX - imageCanvas.offsetLeft;
e.pageY - imageCanvas.offsetTop;
```

With this you will get the position of the cursor relative to the *canvas* element.

Now, you need to subtract the `x` and `y` values that you stored on `dragstart`, and that will give you the `left` and `top` values of the upper-left corner of the dragged image, relative to the *canvas* element:

```
image.style.left = (e.pageX - imagesCanvas.offsetLeft - x) + 'px';
image.style.top = (e.pageY - imagesCanvas.offsetTop - y) + 'px';
```

All together it will look like this:

```js
let x;
let y;
let currentTarget = null;
let cloneElement = false;

function startDrag(e, clone) {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if (target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;
    currentTarget = target;
    cloneElement = clone;
  }
}

function cloneImage(e) {
  startDrag(e, true);
}

function moveImage(e) {
  startDrag(e, false);
}

function removeImage(e) { 
  if (!cloneElement) {
    currentTarget.remove();
  }
}

function stickImage(e) { 
  const image = cloneElement ? currentTarget.cloneNode(true) : currentTarget;
  
  imagesCanvas.appendChild(image);
  
  // + 1 for the border
  
  image.style.left = (e.pageX - imagesCanvas.offsetLeft - x + 1) + 'px';
  image.style.top = (e.pageY - imagesCanvas.offsetTop - y + 1) + 'px';
  
  currentTarget = null;
}

function allowDrag(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

// Bind event listeners:

const imagesBarElement = document.getElementById('imagesBar');
const imagesCanvasElement = document.getElementById('imagesCanvas');

document.addEventListener('dragenter', allowDrag);
document.addEventListener('dragover', allowDrag);

imagesBarElement.addEventListener('dragstart', cloneImage);
imagesBarElement.addEventListener('drop', removeImage);

imagesCanvasElement.addEventListener('dragstart', moveImage);
imagesCanvasElement.addEventListener('drop', stickImage);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  user-select: none;
}

img {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#imagesBar {
  height: 64px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#imagesBar > img {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

#imagesCanvas {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#imagesCanvas > img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesBar">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/2000_Ford_Racing_Puma_16V_1.7_Front.jpg/2880px-2000_Ford_Racing_Puma_16V_1.7_Front.jpg" draggable="true">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/AC_Shelby_Cobra_427_Oldtimertreffen_Ebern_2019_6200154.jpg/2880px-AC_Shelby_Cobra_427_Oldtimertreffen_Ebern_2019_6200154.jpg" draggable="true">   
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Lotus_Elise_Sport_220%2C_Paris_Motor_Show_2018%2C_IMG_0277.jpg/2880px-Lotus_Elise_Sport_220%2C_Paris_Motor_Show_2018%2C_IMG_0277.jpg" draggable="true">   
</div>

<div id="imagesCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: @Yikes Which part is not working exactly? Do you mean by _snap together_ that you just want the images to appear aligned side by side instead of being able to move them freely to any arbitrary position?

Comment: No, you understood perfectly what I wanted it to do (and thank you for taking the time to write all this out)! Just for whatever reason, when I tried running this code, not even normal drop worked. The images would just bounce back to their original position. I couldn't even test the part that snapped them together.

Comment: @Yikes Which browser and version are you using? As I said in the answer, some of those cursor position properties may need polyfilling or being replaced by a different or a combination of different ones.

Comment: I'm using Safari for all my testing. Would you recommend I try it in Chrome or another browser and see how it goes?

Comment: Yes please, try in Chrome for example. I will take a look in Safari tomorrow.

Comment: @Yikes I tried in Safari and got the following error `Can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property`. Fixed it by changing the name of the variables, so it should work fine now. See here for more information on that Safari issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091136/cant-create-duplicate-variable-that-shadows-a-global-property

Comment: Oh thanks so much! That was super helpful!! My only issue is now they're snapping on top of each other. I was having some issues with using the imagesCanvas.offSetTop because it kept snapping to the top of the page. I edited it to: `image.style.left = (ev.clientX - x + 1) + 'px';`. If you have any ideas to stop the overlapping, let me know! Thank you so much for all your help so far. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Yikes I guess the overlapping is normal if you drop images on top of each other, but you can still move them around as many times as you want. What would be the expected behaviour when an image is dropped occupying the space of an existing one? Should it be moved away automatically?

Comment: The issue is if I snap it anywhere near another image, it snaps on top instead of snapping below or on the side of the image.

Comment: I should clarify, they don't snap directly on top of each other. They snap overlapping each other. I want them to snap directly below each other or directly left of each other. I'm not quite sure why it keeps overlapping. I've tried a few different things to fix it (including jQuery) but nothing seems to work). Once again, thank you so much for all your help so far!! If you have any more suggestions on that or any documentation you recommend I read (I've read a ton so far), let me know!

Comment: @Yikes The target of the `drop` event will be the element the image was dropped to. Therefore, if `e.target.tagName === 'IMG'`, you know you dropped the image on top of another image and can use it's `offsetLeft`, `offsetWidth` and `offsetTop` properties to place the new one next to it.

Comment: However, that will not solve your problem completely, as it is still possible that there's an image already on that position as well. What you need to do is loop throw all the images while moving a cursor representing the destination position for the new image. I would also advise you to store the position and dimension of each image in an object, that you update on each drop, and loop that instead of getting the images from the DOM.