# JavaScript not working on Safari (Mac and iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, jekyll

I've implemented an instant search function using javascript on my jekyll site:
https://cecilialee.github.io (Repository: https://github.com/cecilialee/cecilialee.github.io)

It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. However, when I test it on Safari, no matter on Mac or iPhone, the script doesn't seem working..

What can I do?

Answer (score 9):

Ok I found the answer.

When I inspect on Safari, I found `SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property: 'results'`.

> This is apparently a problem Safari has with declaring a let/const
>   variable that shares the same name as a selected id attribute. I had
>   some variables declared with const as you did and got the same error.
>   Changed to let and still got it. Changed to var and it worked.

Reference:
["can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091136/cant-create-duplicate-variable-that-shadows-a-global-property)

Hence, I changed some of my JavaScript const to avoid duplication with id. And the script works like a charm again!