# Safari 11.1 Issue - Can't create duplicate variable: "typeMap" , ckeditor 4.9.1

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Does anyone have a workaround for the issue caused by Safari 11.1 - SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: "typeMap'.
You can see the error on the [ckeditor-4 home page](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/), and as shown in the image below.
This article seems to explain the reason [can't create duplicate variable that shadows a global property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091136/cant-create-duplicate-variable-that-shadows-a-global-property), but I have no idea how to work around it, if that is even possible. 
Any suggestions?
[Here is a screen grab of error in safari 11.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uVWJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error for the variable contentORIGINAL which was related to the Safari extension JSON Peep 1.3

Disabling the extension removed the error.

I came across this question when searching for that particular combination of error message and ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the Safari Extension called AdBlock. I've created a ticket with them about it. It seems to be related to contenteditable in general as it affects other editors too:

https://help.getadblock.com/support/tickets/23147

Comment: I don't have AdBlock installed, just LastPass and Boomerang and I have disabled both of them - but still get this error message.